# Create a Public Download Link for my Attachment

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdistribution

I have an Object which has attachments and I can access those using ContentDocument and ContentVersions. but when i try to create a download link for the same using ContentDistribution I am able to generate the link. but it navigates me to a Content Distribution page and there i see the public Link.. Is there any way we can create a proper public link in code itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the contentDistribution and use [DistributionPublicUrl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm) field value for getting URL of the link to the shared document..

Just in case you want downlodable url, you can use

ContentDownloadUrl - The link for downloading the file. This field is available in API version 40.0 and later.

Comment: HI Thanks for your response, I tried this but ContentDistribution object is not having any of 'DisributionPublicURL' / ContentDownloadURL. What can be done ?